# Dev environment is not working after restoring DB in Microsoft dynamics 365

Tags: ssms, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

The restore of the Database in Dev environment is completed and followed all the required steps (I have already restored DB once without any errors).

Now after the Dev restore, I'm not able to open my Dev environment.
**Error :** Sorry, we lost the connection temporarily. Please be patient while we reconnect you.

And restarted the IIS services and getting **error :** Metadata service communication retry attempts failed to resolve issues with the following settings AX7CertificateUserName: FRServiceUser@dynamics.com; AX7CertificateThumbprint: ; AX7FederationRealm: spn:; AX7ProviderName: https://mintedtoken.dynamics.com; AX7TokenIssuer: https://fakeacs.accesscontrol.windows.net/
Component: Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Common.TraceLog
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Machine: SIG-ERP-DEV-1

Tried all the possible ways and still dev environment is not working.

Comment: It's working after DB sync and build model

Comment: is this IFD (internet-facing deployment)?